# The expansion files plus icon in google play console is removed?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Good day.

My project file size was greater than the maximum allowed limit in google play. so right now,  I'm just trying to learn the expansion files offered by google.

My problem is, I don't get it why I can't find the plus icon after I uploaded my second apk version on my play console? The post here in StackOverflow says that the plus icon will only appear after the second version that you uploaded. but in my case, even I already uploaded many versions of the app, the plus icon still not visible to me.

Here is the plus icon that I am looking for. This image is taken from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkQx3xP0W6A&t=192s
[image: plus icon]

And here is mine 
[image]

I read already the guide from this link https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files and they don't mention how to upload the expansion file from play console.

There are many threads here in StackOverflow that talking about expansion files but most of them are posted 7 years ago. Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion files are a feature that exists only for APKs.

Android App Bundles have two replacement features: [dynamic delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) and [asset delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery) are built-in and make it easier to deliver additional features or assets to the device, at **install-time**, at **fast-follow** after initial install, or anytime **on-demand**.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I see. My mistake when I mention apk version in my post even I uploaded an app bundle but not an apk.  Yes! and it works. I thought app bundle and apk are the same. my mistake. Thanks.